# Calculated Column to get previous year

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a Date table and I want to create a calculated column that gives me the date of the previous year. For example, if the date is 2018 then Previous_Year column should be 2017.

Current Column is [_Year]
New Calculated Column is [Previous_Year]

In Dax this is what I have [Previous_Year]= DATE(YEAR([_Year]-1,YEAR))

thanks

Comment: Please provide an example

Comment: what is problem with the formula?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Previous_Year = YEAR('Datetable'[_Year])-1)
```

I am presuming that [_Year] holds a datevalue and that you want the year of that date minus 1.